# Insert data into a table with a foreign key SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, backend

I need to insert some data into the 'ItemBook' table after inserting the following values for one row for the 'Item' Table:

```
Name='Clippers', itemLink='amazon.com' description='hair clippers'
```

Now I would also like to insert some data to the ItemBook table as well but I am not sure on how to do this with a table that has a foreign key. Here is the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
itemLink VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);

CREATE TABLE ItemBook (
ItemName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Publisher VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ItemName),
FOREIGN KEY (ItemName) REFERENCES Item(Name)
);
```

My attempt:

```
INSERT INTO itemBook (Name, Publisher)
VALUES ('Clippers', 'Bob');
```

Error Msg:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.
```

Other Attempt:

```
INSERT INTO eventbook (EventName, Publisher)
SELECT E.name
FROM event E
WHERE E.name = eventbook.EventName;
```

Error Message:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'eventbook.EventName' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: There's no magic here. Just insert your row in ItemBook as you normally would, ensuring that the ItemName column matches a value in the Name column of your Items table

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular can you show me with an example? Ive posted my attempt above. Im just not familiar with the syntax

Comment: your attempt doesn't reference either of the tables you've listed.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag the actual DBMS you are using and not just random others. It seems you are not using SSMS or SQL Server so perhaps that is part of your issue? But to insert a row into ItemBook, the name you supply must already exist in Item. You are creating a 1:1 relationship between Item and ItemBook - was that your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason to not use integer IDs? I would do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
Id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
itemLink VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE ItemBook (
Id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ItemName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Publisher VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ItemId INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES Item(Id)
);

INSERT INTO ItemBook Values(1, 'ItemName', 'Publisher', 0)
```

What are your thoughts?

Edit 1. Based on your response and example, I have produced the following SQL for SQLITE (should work fine in other DBs as well)

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ItemLink VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);

CREATE TABLE ItemBook (
ItemName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Publisher VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ItemName),
FOREIGN KEY (ItemName) REFERENCES Item(Name)
);

INSERT INTO Item (Name, ItemLink, Description) VALUES("Test Book", "http://www.testlink.com/", "This is a test book");

INSERT INTO ItemBook (ItemName, Publisher) Values("Test Book", "Test Publisher");

SELECT * FROM Item i JOIN ItemBook b on b.ItemName = i.Name
```

[Check the result in this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWvd6.png)

Comment: Its an assignment, and the script they gave worked fine in creating the tables. I just need to insert the data into the other table

Comment: Then Tangentially Perpendicular's answer will work fine!

Comment: Can you please show me an example of that insertion? Im very confused on this aspect. I have posted my attempt

Comment: Hi DreamVision2017, I have updated my answer. Sorry for the long time, I was having dinner. SMor, try to be less rude, thanks.